# selenium testing a tooltip for an inactive button

Tags: selenium, button, webdriver, tooltip

on whom I am able to click, on clicking , nothing happens, i.e. the action is disabled. However, a tooltip gets displayed. The tooltip appears only when we focus on the button.

The html of the button is as follows:

```
     <button type="button" style="color:#ffffff;" rel="rel-517347" data-toggle="popover" data-animation="true" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-content="<span class='text-center'>
    <div>Ride can only be edited before </div><div>1 hour of pickup time.</div>
</span>" class="btn btn-default disbleBtn width_100" data-original-title="" title="">Edit Ride</button>
```

where Ride can only be edited before  is the tooltip.

How can i verify the text of the tooltip as it keeps getting destroyed.

Note that isEnabled() function returns true here as i can click on the button, but no action takes place.

Is there any way I can verify the class of the button i.e btn btn-default disbleBtn width_100 ?
Is there any function or method for it?

Comment: _able to click, on clicking , nothing happens_, _tooltip appears only when we focus on the button_, _verify the text of the tooltip_? What is your exact _usecase_? What are you trying to do? Which Selenium binding _Java_ / _Python_? Your code trials and error?

Comment: selenium using Java. I click on a button. Clicking on the button will do nothing, but display a tooltip. i.e. enclosed inside the div tag. How can I verify the contents of the tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supposed you need to hover not click on the button. When hover tooltip is showing and than you click immediately and tooltip gone.
Do it manually with chrome devtools, open devtools-> sources tab, hover on the button and press F8 to pause then inspect tooltip element. After you get selector for tooltip try codes below:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(buttonElement).perform();
String tooltipText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(toolTipLocator).getText();
//Verify
```

Or try this:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(buttonElement).perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(toolTipLocator, textToVerify)
```

Comment: Thanks alot once again Sers. is there also any way I can fetch the class of the span i.e. "btn btn-default disbleBtn width_100" and display it?

Comment: @Radhika what do you mean? You want to check if button has class and make button visible?

Comment: Also my button is not a web element but a String element enclosed in a By.xpath condition.

Comment: Yes @Sers i want to check if the button has a class, print it using sysout and make the button visible.

Comment: <button type="button" style="color:#ffffff;" rel="rel-517347" data-toggle="popover" data-animation="true" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-content="<span class='text-center'>
    <div>Ride can only be edited before </div><div>1 hour of pickup time.</div>
</span>" class="btn btn-default disbleBtn width_100" data-original-title="" title="">Edit Ride</button>

Comment: my tooltip is inside the div tag.

Comment: To check if element has class use `element.getAttribute("class").contains("width_100")`. To show tooltip there is some javascript showing tooltip using html in `data-content` attribute, just use code in my answer to hover and will shown. You can get data-content value like `element.getAttribute("data-content")` then remove to not necessary strings like span, div

Comment: Thanks once again :)